# Given the union of a cylinder and a sphere calculate the line integral using Stoke's theorem

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, parametrization, line-integrals, stokes-theorem

Given the surface $S=S_1\cup S_2$ where $S_1=\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 / x^2+y^2=1 ;  \space 0 \leq z\leq1 \}$ and $S_2=\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 / x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2=1 ;  \space  z\geq1 \}$, orientated with the normal pointing outside the cylinder (with cap) and the sphere, respectively.

Let $F(x,y,z)=(zx + z^2y+x, z^3yx+y,z^4x^2)$. Calculate $\int_S (\nabla \times F)\space   dS$

Then, because Stoke's theorem we have that: 
$\int_S (\nabla \times F)\space   dS= \int_{C_{1}} F \space   dS + \int_{C_{2}} F \space   dS$
Where, $C_1$ is the simple-closed curve of the cylinder, and $C_2$ of the half of the sphere.

I'm having troubles about defining the appropriate orientation of the curve to make the normal vector pointing outside both surfaces, and also I wonder if I should or not parametrize them with polar coordinates. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I think that, according to Stokes, you should have $\int_S (\nabla \times F) dS = \int_C F ds,$ where $C$ is the circle $x^2+y^2 = 1, \, z=0.$ Try drawing your surface.

Comment: I already drew my surface, and is a cylinder from $z=0$ up to $z=1$ and then you have as the rest of $S$ the half part of a sphere, where both figures have the same radius, equal to 1.

Comment: Great! Can you see that the boundary of the surface is the circle $C$ from my first comment?

Comment: Yes, but what about the plane $z=0$, that is like the cylinder base? That also give as another curve for the cylinder

Comment: That part is not included in your surface. Your surface has a sort of a "hole" in the bottom part. So your boundary is just the circle $x^2 + y^2= 1, \, z=0.$

Comment: Okay, cool. Then, should I use polar coordinates as parametrization right?

Comment: Polar coordinates should work great here, yes!

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $\mathbf F(x, y, 0) = (x, y, 0)$ and the boundary of the surface is $(\cos t, \sin t, 0)$, therefore $\mathbf F \cdot d\mathbf s = 0$.